# Gist in blogger dynamic views

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, blogger, gist, blogger-dynamic-views

I want to embed my gists ([gist.github](https://gist.github.com/)) in my blogger blog. But as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179467/adding-script-tag-in-blogger-dynamic-view) question dynamic views directly don't support javascript.

From the moski's(as mentioned in the answer) blog its possible to embed a gist.

What if I want to only embed only one file of my gist?

For example:

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/3975635.js?file=regcomp.c"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at moski's blog, his description and gist snippets ([gistLoader.js](https://raw.github.com/moski/gist-Blogger/master/public/gistLoader.js) and [gistBlogger.js](https://raw.github.com/moski/gist-Blogger/master/public/gistBlogger.js)), I can suppose that to reach your goal you have to edit that code a little bit.

Currently, when you add

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/moski/gist-Blogger/master/public/gistLoader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

at the bottom of your posts, what this script does is looking for this other code you added into your blog

```
<div class="gistLoad" data-id="GistID" id="gist-GistID">Loading ....</div>
```

retrieves the `data-id` attribute, and injects the required code to load the script with `src` set to

```
'https://gist.github.com/' + id + '.js'
```

Now, if I correctly figured out what the code does, editing the second moski's HTML code in  this way:

```
<div class="gistLoad" data-id="GistID" data-file="GistFile" id="gist-GistID">Loading ....</div>
```

and the function in moski's `gistBlogger.js` in order to retrieve (when defined) the new `data-file` attribute, you can generate a new `src` to inject, like that:

```
'https://gist.github.com/' + id + '.js?file=' + file
```

It should works.